# Decrypt external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, decryption

How can I decrypt an external (USB) hard drive in Ubuntu 18.04? Unfortunately I can't remember how I encrypted it.

I want to remove the encryption because currently I can only access the files on it from Ubuntu (after typing the passphrase), while I also want to access the files on it from a Windows computer.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you used the Disks manager to encrypt the partition. I've done the same on my USB drive.

How you did it doesn't matter since you're going to format back you USB drive to FAT system

Just copy the files on your computer, format it FAT32 with the Disks tool, and copy back your files on your USB drive

Comment: Bonjour B. du Garay!
Do you think this question of mine could be solved with your above solution?
https://askubuntu.com/posts/1399372/revisions
Merci beaucoup,
Johann